# No communication possible with CAN vector Device using python-can

Tags: can-bus, python-can

### Objectif :

Send and receive data with a VN1630A Vector device from python script.

### Tools used

- python-can
- cantools

### Details

I am currently trying to send and receive data from a python script on a CAN communication using a VN1630A device. I can see my device on Vector Hardware manager. No other applications are running when I trz except VScode and Vector HardWare Manager. I have configured 2 channel on the software to a specific "python-can" application.

I am using the specific Vector interface of cantools to connect.

I made a dbc Can file with specific messages.

my python script

```py
from typing import Optional
import can
import cantools
from can.interfaces import vector
from can import typechecking

MASTER_TO_SLAVE_MSG = "Master_to_slave_standard_msg"

class MasterVectorCAN():
    def __init__(self, channel, dbc_file_path):
        self.channel = channel
        self.dbc_file_path = dbc_file_path
        self.bus = None

        self.db = None
    def open(self):
        """
        Ouvre le bus de communication.
        """
        try:
            self.bus = vector.VectorBus(bitrate=500000, channel=self.channel,app_name="python-can")
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Erreur lors de l'ouverture du bus : {e}")
            return False

    def send(self, counter, Command_sg,Num_selector,Table_Selector, extended_id=False):
        """
        Envoie un message sur le bus de communication.

        Args:
            message_id (int): L'identifiant du message CAN.
            data (bytes): Les données à envoyer.
            extended_id (bool, optional): Si True, utilise un identifiant étendu (29 bits). Sinon, utilise un identifiant standard (11 bits). Par défaut, False.

        Returns:
            bool: True si l'envoi a réussi, False sinon.
        """
        try:

            data = {"Counter":counter,"Command_sg":Command_sg,"Num_selector":Num_selector,"Table_Selector":Table_Selector}
            can_msg = self.encode_message(MASTER_TO_SLAVE_MSG,data=data)
            self.bus.send(can_msg)
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Erreur lors de l'envoi du message : {e}")
            return False

    def receive(self, timeout=None):
        """
        Reçoit un message depuis le bus de communication.

        Args:
            timeout (float, optional): Temps d'attente maximal en secondes. Si None, la fonction bloque jusqu'à ce qu'un message soit reçu. Par défaut, None.

        Returns:
            can.Message: Le message reçu, ou None en cas d'expiration du timeout.
        """
        try:
            return self.bus.recv(timeout=timeout)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Erreur lors de la réception du message : {e}")
            return None

    def load_dbc_file(self):
        """
        Charge la configuration depuis un fichier DBC.

        Returns:
            bool: True si le chargement a réussi, False sinon.
        """
        try:
            self.bus.set_filters([{"dbc": self.dbc_file_path}])
            self.db = cantools.database.load_file(self.dbc_file_path)
            self.master_msg = self.db.get_message_by_name(MASTER_TO_SLAVE_MSG)
            return True
        
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Erreur lors du chargement du fichier DBC : {e}")
            return False


    def close(self):
        """
        Ferme le bus de communication.
        """
        if self.bus is not None:
            self.bus.shutdown()
            self.bus = None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    channel = 0  # Channel du bus CAN Vector (peut varier selon la configuration matérielle)
    dbc_file_path = "C:\\Users\\MPI4ABT\\Documents\\MATLAB\\Can_db.dbc"
    interface = "vector"
    vector_can = MasterVectorCAN(channel, dbc_file_path)
    print("Instantiated")
    if vector_can.open():
        print("Opened")
        vector_can.load_dbc_file()

        # Exemple d'envoi de données
        message_id = 0x123
        data = b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08'
        vector_can.send(counter=b'x01',Command_sg=b'x01',Num_selector=b'0011',Table_Selector=b'x01',extended_id=False)

        # Exemple de réception de données avec un timeout de 1 seconde
        received_message = vector_can.receive(timeout=1)
        if received_message:
            print(f"Message reçu : {received_message}")

        vector_can.close()
```

I am currently sending a random message and receiving whatever. However, When I run my script, the debugger blocks on `self.bus = vector.VectorBus(bitrate=500000, channel=self.channel,app_name="python-can")`without any error, it just blocks. There is no similar issues on the python-can documentation (Using the version 4.2.2). So it blocks on it and do not go further.

No way found to solve this issue except diving into the vector specific API which could take me a year to resolve this issue.

Comment: Just checked on my machine, I can get a connection. Could you maybe share a screenshot of the application channel assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Okay Sorry Actually it was because of the Vector License issue whoch was not functionning. I used the old vector software tools and it worked.