# CANoe settings for intercepting messages sent on Virtual Can Bus with python

Tags: python, can-bus, canoe, python-can

**Purpose:**
I want to send data on Virtual Can Bus using Python and then check in CANoe if the request is tracked, but nothing happens.
I use a Sample Configuration (ex UDSBasic.cfg) from the CANoe and I do not know if I have to change the Network Hardware or Diagnostic/ISO TP to intercept the message.

**What have I tried:**
I found a lot of code about the use of python-can library, but nothing about how to configure canoe o intercept the messages sent with Python on a virtual bus

```py
import udsoncan
import time
from can.interfaces.vector import VectorBus
from isotp import Address, CanStack
from udsoncan.connections import PythonIsoTpConnection


try:
    # Link Layer (CAN protocol)
    bus = VectorBus(interface='vector', app_name='CANoe', channel=0, bitrate=500000)
    # Network layer addressing scheme
    tp_addr = Address(txid=0x701, rxid=0x601)
    # Network/Transport layer (IsoTP protocol)
    stack = CanStack(bus=bus, address=tp_addr)
    # Interface between Application and Transport layer
    conn = PythonIsoTpConnection(stack)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

udsoncan.setup_logging()
conn.open()

# send 1 req/sec
for i in range(10):
    # Send test req
    req = b"\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03\x03"
    conn.send(req)
    #resp = conn.wait_frame().hex()
    time.sleep(1)
    
conn.close()
```

When I run this code, I saw in Vector Hardware Manager, the bus gets some messages while script is running, but in CANoe it doesn't appear anywhere. I think I'm missing some configuration for intercepting the message

[Vector Hardware Manager config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVCKE.png)

CANoe project config (UDSBasic.cfg): default settings

**Simmilar topics:**

[No communication possible with CAN vector Device using python-can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76828417/no-communication-possible-with-can-vector-device-using-python-can)

[How to debug isotp connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77939665/how-to-debug-isotp-connection)

Comment: You should create a dedicated application for your python script in the hardware manager (and use that application name in your script).l Then you assign the same channel of the virtual can bus to both your application and CANoe.